# Log Event Details Window is Not Showing Up in Data Stage Designer (IBM)

Tags: debugging, datastage

I can't see the detailed job log message from IBM Data Stage Designer (client) from a few days ago. I had worked well by double-clicking the log message on the job log panel, but suddenly it has been stopped to show up in the popup windows.

I tried to push the key combination: Shift + Window + Left/Right arrows, but it still does not provide the job log window. Could anyone has an idea how to make it visible again? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with multiple monitors, maybe on a laptop, changing the connected monitors, then maybe the popup window is showing "outside the box". You already tried to fix it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>, *but this type of modal window will not stick to that*.

Instead, try the following procedure:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> while the window has focus. This will bring up the context menu of the window.
2. Use the arrow keys <kbd>↑</kbd>,<kbd>↓</kbd> to select `Move` and press <kbd>↵</kbd>Enter. Do *not* click on it using the mouse.
3. The window is now in moving state. Press any arrow key <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>, just one keystroke.
4. Now, the window will be stuck to the mouse. Move the mouse around (without clicking) to retrieve the window.
5. Click once to release the window from the mouse.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I'm using multiple monitors and I couldn't understand why it happened every time. Your reply is really helpful for me and now it works well. Thanks again.